# CSOM: Determine if the List / Library is visible in the UI

Tags: csom

I'm new to SharePoint CSOM and I'm trying to get a list of SP Lists/Libraries.

Here's my code:

```
public LinkedList<string> getLibraries() {
        Web site = spClientContext.Web;
        spClientContext.Load(site.Lists);
        spClientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        LinkedList<string> libraries = new LinkedList<string>();
        foreach (List list in site.Lists)
            libraries.AddLast(list.Title);

        return libraries;
    }
```

When code is executed CSOM returns all libraries, even those that are hidden from the web interface.
Something like this:

[image: CSOM returned libraries]
[image: SharePoint 2010 libraries]

How can I determine which List/Library to display in my list so that it matches SharePoint UI visible lists?

Comment: Found an similar Stack Overflow article here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293861/filtering-out-hidden-and-system-sharepoint-folders-on-windows-phone-7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check `list.Hidden` property, then add in `libraries`

```
foreach(List list in site.Lists) {
    if (!list.Hidden) {
        libraries.AddLast(list.Title);
    }
}
```

Comment: One more question, I have the similar issue with folders, I getting folders which are not visible in the Web UI. Folder's do not have the Hidden property, how do I filter those?

Comment: Please ask another question with code